# JSLint error in grunt build, Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,» (line: 123565, col: 69, pos: 4239698)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, ecmascript-5

```
/*jshint esnext: true */

function getListOfVas(customer, OfferingSubCategory, generalFilters=null){
};
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`esnext` is deprecated](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esnext). Try `esversion: 6` instead.

Comment: line 26  col 77  'default parameters' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option).      esversion: 6 not working

Answer (score 0):

change `generalFilters=null` to  `generalFilters`  for the *ECMAScript 6* syntax

Comment: Build is giving error only in my system's local grunt build not in other's systems. If that "=" is an issue, It should be everywhere.

Comment: moreover the first line is only for allowing the es6 syntax.

Comment: Why should TO not use default parameters? O.o